# How to get name instead of foreign id in Laravel crud views

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

So I want to get the name instead of the foreign key in the read view and I want to turn the name to foreign id in the create and edit view

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>manufacturer_id:</strong>
                    {!! Form::text('manufacturer_id', null, array('placeholder' => 'manufacturer_id','class' => 'form-control')) !!}                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

I think I can get the name instead of the foreign key in the read view by using $computer->manufaturer->name. but still don't know how to solve the create and edit view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the list of manufacturers from your controller.

```
$manufacturers = Manufacturer::pluck('name', 'id');
```

Change the view with following syntex

```
{!! Form::select('manufacturer_id', $manufacturers, null, ['placeholder' => 'Select manufacturer', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```